# Combined distinct values for 2 tables needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and need to get the distinct combined results between them.

```
TABLE1:
A
B
C

TABLE2:
A
D
E

DESIRED RESULT:
A
B
C
D
E
```

Anyone know the SQL for to get this result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, `union` should work:

```
select * from table 1 
union 
select * from table 2
```

Comment: Looks like you were the fastest :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` query to get the distinct results from both tables

```
select yourCol
from table1
union
select yourCol
from table2
```

The `UNION` will remove any duplicate values. If you wanted to return all values including duplicates then you could use a `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what a `UNION` is for;

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

You should of course preferably use column names instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COL_NAME FROM TABLE1
UNION 
SELECT COL_NAME FROM TABLE2
-- THIS THIS COMBINATION OF RESULT SETS
--THIS IS EXAMPLE IN EMP, DEPT TABLE

select DEPTNO from emp
union
select DEPTNO from dept

DEPTNO
----------
    10
    20
    30
    40
```